# Where can I see what systems are checking CA Server Certificates

Tags: windows, certificate, ca

I am trying to clean up a domain's Certificate Authority Server (CA server), by which I mean Decomm it.  It has recently issued certificates, mostly for the domain controllers and I have an article from Microsoft on how to decom the server that will take care of those.
However, it has some issued for Code Signing and one for a Hardware Token for singing in.  I need to know if those certificates are being used.  I'm just coming into this environment and don't know if/where/why they would be used and the person who set them up is no longer employed with the company, so I have to figure it out.

I'm not seeing any way to tell if there is something out there checking on the validity of these certificates - nothing in event logs, no CA Logs that I can read, No "Workstation74 checked certificate 12 at 2:36 PM" entries that I can find.

I've "googled" and looked in CA Services, event logs, etc.  It seems like such a no-brainer that there would be an obvious way to check and see if something is reaching out to check the validity of a certificate on the certificate server - but nope..
Like when checking to see if anything is still pointed at a DNS server, you turn on logging and go through the log entries to find things still asking the server for DNS and set that system to dhcp or point it to the new DNS sever...